Graph Coloring Decision Problem Reduction to Prove NP-Complete
I am doing research into NP-Complete problems and more specifically started looking into the Graph Coloring Decision Problem or the k-Coloring problem, as described here:

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ is the set of edge relations, can you assign some given set of colors to $G$ such that two vertices that are connected by an edge are not assigned the same color.

I have found a number of different proofs demonstrating the problem's NP-Completeness by a reduction from another known NP-Complete problem. However, after seeing a reduction from the 3-SAT problem to the 3-Coloring problem, I began to wonder if the SAT problem is reducible to the k-Coloring problem directly and not transitively. I tried looking into it and I cannot seem to find anywhere that describes such a reduction.
So, my question is, does anyone know if a reduction from SAT to k-Coloring has already been done? If so, what does it look like/how does it work? Are there any papers out there that I simply missed that go over this problem?

SAT can be reduced to 3-SAT in a straightforward way (the Tseitin transform), and you seem to be aware that 3-SAT can be reduced to 3-coloring (e.g., https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~lalla/373s16/notes/3col.pdf, https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~anuprao/pubs/CSE531Sp2020/lecture7.pdf), and 3-coloring can be reduced to $k$-coloring in a straightforward way (just set $k=3$).
Then it is straightforward (but tedious) to compose the reductions and obtain a direct reduction from SAT to $k$-coloring.  I don't think it will add any insight beyond knowing how each of those individual reductions work, but you can certainly construct it.

Any NP-Complete problem can be reduced to one another since, by definition, they are all equally hard (under polynomial reducibility). As pointed out by @D.W., it might not be worthwhile trying to get into a complicated reduction in this case compared to the existing convenient two-step proof.

Yeah that all makes sense. I am aware of the multi-step proof to show that k-coloring is in NP-Complete from SAT to 3-SAT to 3-Coloring to k-Coloring, and I am also aware that theoretically, all NP-Complete problems must be able reduce to one another by definition in some way. I was just interested in seeing if anyone was aware of the existence of a proof that showed that SAT can reduce directly to k-coloring. However, I do also understand that understanding/spending time on a proof like this is basically a waste of time but, that didn't stop me from being curious.
